# Newbie need Help: Database login and user management schema and Dealing with jframe and jdialog form Netbeans 8 Java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7, netbeans-8

Hello all affter searching for what is a batter programming language for me im decided to learn Java using netbeans and mysql as a database.

I have a small project to help me understanding java my small project is to create item storage application, is a simple application and all the project documentary i will publish on my blog that i will create affter the project done so every one can learn java. But first I need help on desining a database schame for user and user login for admin and user. for now my data base is
only one database that contain all user profil. 
id as primary and auto increment, user kode unique, fname,lname,username,pass,usergrub,adress,email,and other that other just for complement. is this a right way to store data in database with this kind of database column.

or could you give me a example user managemen and login database schame so i can learn from it, i have search on google it's hard to find

for it and my other problem is on using Jframe so i can show jdialog when user click the jmenu insde the jframe it will open a jdialog, the other problem is when user click twice jmenu User>user login  or other menu wich contain acction performent the code is just dialogform df= new dialogform;df.set.visible(true) is there any way to perform this so every time user doing clik more then one to that menu the menu dont open twice or more.

The question would be continue in this Question page so every one I NEED HELP.

Comment: Don't store passwords, store a one way hash of password instead, this way if the database is compromised, you don't expose the user passwords. Most of the rest of the structure will come down to personal preference and needs.  For example, you could store the user (personal) details and the user details in a separate tables

Comment: [How NOT to Store Passwords! - Computerphile (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q)

Comment: Just and idea of managing the users and roles, dont know whether its the best practice --> [User and Role Management](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9u7pvseL-_7T3ZKTmZXbTVNR3c/view?pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

Before you create a database you should know which data are needed, which should be stored inside a table and which should be separated. Also you should remove redundant columns in a table if another table has it.
Here is a link to download the [Northwind Database Schema](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwb2iETeJLKTZnpPVHF6Ui1PSVk). You can learn from its structure on how to properly Create and **Normalize** a database your building. [Here is a youtube link on how to do Normalization.](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQtwIwBWoVChMIwbzjnp2MyAIVxBiUCh285grG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DU-F_fRJ_YTQ&usg=AFQjCNGGsUvBO7SEVOipE09Ylupq-BnmYw&sig2=UpAi1JdiiWcfNiGcxY0Z_g)

Also You **DONT** store passwords you encrypt it first to prevent others from viewing the save passwords in your database. Use **MD5 Hash**. [Here is a MD5 hsahing example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-md5-hashing-example/)

As for the Login examle you can just search on google. [here is an example of login form in java using mysql database](http://www.lionblogger.com/java-application-mysql-database/)

Lastly, you should also learn how to create Java Applications, please read this [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to better understand the concept of swing applications